# How to append binary data to a HSQL(2.3.2) blob?

Tags: java, blob, hsqldb

i am using *HSQL 2.3.2* and i have a table structure like this:

```
create table test (name varchar(255), data blob);
```

i know how to insert binary data into the table:

```
// ... insert omitted ...
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("update test set data = ? where name = 'chris'");

final Blob bb = connection.createBlob();

final OutputStream out = bb.setBinaryStream(bb.length()+1);
out.write(("[test "+System.currentTimeMillis()+"]").getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.flush();
out.close();

ps.setBlob(1,bb);

ps.execute();
```

its possible to use ps.setBinaryStream(1,...); too, ok.

But **how can i add/append data to an existing blob?** i tryed:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test where name = 'chris'");

if(rs.next())
{
    Blob b = rs.getBlob("data");
    if(b!=null)
    {
    System.out.println("Blob size: " + b.length());

    System.out.println("content: " + StringUtils.asString(b.getBinaryStream()));

    final OutputStream out = b.setBinaryStream(b.length());
    out.write(("[test "+System.currentTimeMillis()+"]").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    System.out.println("Blob size after write: " + b.length());

}
else
{
    System.out.println("no blob found.");
}
```

but all i get is:

```
Blob size: 20
content: [test 1412778939148]
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: feature not supported
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.notSupported(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCBlobClient.setBinaryStream(Unknown Source)
    at aniclo.server.STest.main(STest.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

so this means HSQL doesnt support appending data? Or what do i miss?
There seems to be a [JDBCBlobClient](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCBlobClient.html) class which mentions that it's workin with a pointer to the blob instead of in-memory binary array representation. Can someone show me how to work with this class?

My application has to support appending data. So the workaround i can think of right now is to create a table and put all data chunks there (like postgres LOB table) and once i got all chunks append them together and move them into the final table, already get a headache when thinking of it ...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Updating and appending data to blobs is supported by HSQLDB. Instead of Blob.setBinaryStream(...)  use Blob.setBytes(...).